# UIButton addTarget: self ... causes "Does not recognize selector" error

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I initialised my UIButton-deriver liek this:

```
Button * it = [[Button alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
```

Then, I do the next:

```
[(UIButton *)self addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[view addSubview:self];
```

The first line causes "Does not recognize selector" error.

Selector buttonClicked: looks like this:

```
-(IBAction) buttonClicked:(id)sender { 
    if (action) action();
    else NSLog(@"Clicked.\n");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Add the action with:

```
[it       addTarget:self 
             action:@selector(buttonClicked:) 
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and then add the button with

```
[view addSubview:it];
```

And don't create UIButtons with init... use the class method + [`buttonWithType:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006815-CH3-SW38).

Be careful to to subclass UIButton, I am not sure if you really want this. Have a look at [create uibutton subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045672/create-uibutton-subclass).

Answer (score 0):

You create buttons with `+(id)buttonWithType:(UIButtonType)buttonType`