# Add gradient to Back button of my UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, gradient, uibarbuttonitem

I have subclassed UINavigationBar and overridden drawRect method so I can add a gradient to it. Now, I want to use the same gradient to the back button, but I don't know what is the easiest way (subclass UIButton, subclass UIBarButton item)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people on StackOverflow caution against subclassing UIButton.
[create uibutton subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045672/create-uibutton-subclass)

The easiest way to do what you want is to use [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom].

Make a transparent .png image of your button and set it as your button.image.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look here:
http://www.cimgf.com/2010/01/28/fun-with-uibuttons-and-core-animation-layers/

Comment: The thing is that I want the default shape of my back button, I just want to add a gradient to it. If I subclass UIButton I don't think I can build the button to have the exact shape.

Answer (score 0):

explore: http://idevrecipes.com/2011/01/12/how-do-iphone-apps-instagramreederdailybooth-implement-custom-navigationbar-with-variable-width-back-buttons/